# What do "PnBS" and "PnMS" mean in FCS flowCore parameters?

Tags: r, flow-cytometry

I'm using the [flowCore](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/flowCore.html) packages to analyze cytometry data, and I am trying to understand all the parameters stored in the FCS file.
I've figured out most of the elements, but despite a thorough search I haven't been able to find documentation on some of the parameters.

For each channel, there are 9 associated parameters. Here's P1 and its associated values from one of my files :

- `$P1N`    FSC-A
- `$P1R`    262144
- `$P1B`    32
- `$P1E`    0,0
- `$P1V`    225
- `$P1G`    1
- `$P1DISPLAY`  LIN
- `$P1BS`   0
- `$P1MS`   0

I've figured out the following from various sources (notably the FCS data standards, given [here](https://isac-net.org/page/Data-Standards)) or from the fields themselves:

- `$PnN` Short name for parameter n.
- `$PnR` Range for parameter number n.
- `$PnB` Number of bits reserved for parameter number n.
- `$PnE` Amplification type for parameter n.
- `$PnV` Detector voltage for parameter n.
- `$PnG` Amplifier gain used for acquisition of parameter n.
- `$PnDISPLAY`  the transformation to apply when displaying the data (e.g. LIN, LOG)

However, these 2 don't appear in the file standard description, and flowCore does not have documentation on the parameters either.

- `$PnBS`
- `$PnMS`

I've seen `$PnBS` set at -1, 0, 48, 57, 54, 52 or 25 for various channels in my data, while `$PnMS` always seems to be at 0.

Does someone know what it is, or where to look for a definition?
If that helps, my FCS files were generated through BD FACSDiva Software Version 9.0.1.

Comment: As this is a package from Bioconductor I would recommend to ask on their site: support.bioconductor.org. Probably you'll get a helpful answer, but it would be nice to know where do you find these parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in [an old mailing list](https://lists.purdue.edu/pipermail/cytometry/2012-June/043612.html). Credit to Josef Spidlen who authored the mail.

*Short answer*: both parameters are proprietary keywords from the BD FACSDiva software for storing scaling values.

*Long answer* from the mailing list:

> **PnBS** Indicates the automatically set Biexponential scale value for Instrument  Parameter (-1 indicates an invalid scale value). When
> importing an FCS  file, if the FCS file has valid Biexponential
> scales, they should be  applied to the data. If the FCS file doesn't
> have valid biexponential  scales then the scales are calculated from
> the entire data. If  biexponential scales exist, then if AUTOBS is
> set, the PnBS values are  used and applied to the data. If AUTOBS is
> not set, the PnMS values are  used and applied to the data. The
> information represented by this keyword becomes part of a Tube's
> attributes, and does not appear in the Tube's list of keywords. It can
> be viewed in the Biexponential inspector' when the auto scaling option
> is selected.
>
> **PnMS** Indicates the manually set Biexponential scale value for Instrument  Parameter (-1 indicates an invalid scale value). When
> importing an FCS  file, if the FCS file has valid Biexponential
> scales, they should be  applied to the data. If the FCS file doesn't
> have valid biexponential  scales then the scales are calculated from
> the entire data. If  biexponential scales exist, then if AUTOBS is
> set, the PnBS values are  used and applied to the data. If AUTOBS is
> not set, the PnMS values are  used and applied to the data. The
> information represented by this keyword becomes part of a Tube's
> attributes, and does not appear in the Tube's list of keywords. It can
> be viewed in the Biexponential inspector' when the manual scaling
> option  is selected.